# calling same threadproc() multiple times, without first call finished

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, winapi, windows-7

i have a threadProc

```
void* ThreadProc(void* xyz)
{
    //do some work..
}
```

now from the main thread.. i call this thread and do not wish to wait for it to finish

```
WaitForSingleObject(hThread, 0)
```

now my flow of program is succh that the case may arrive where
first call to thread is not finished and 2nd time same ThreadProc() is called.

So ...
1. How does OS handles this scenario? Will this kind of program give unexpected results?
2. If this is wrong way of doing it, what is the correct way?

Because ultimately I want one function to be called asynchronously, may be running multiple instances at the same time.

Comment: You can create any number of threads using the same thread function, this is restricted only by available memory. These threads may run concurrently.

Comment: As long as the function is thread-safe (i.e. any shared data it uses with other threads (this thread proc or somewhere else) is properly protected, it should be ok. But be warned: don't overwrite your `hThread` before first closing it or you're going to leak handles (not good).

Comment: thx. Doubt cleared..!

Answer (score 1):

Every thread has a separate stack, so as long as all variables in the thread callback function are local, there are no conflicts. But if you would access variables that are global/static, then they are shared between all threads and all access to them needs to be handled carefully. Use mutex/semaphores/critical sections for such. The same goes for calling library functions which you don't know are thread-safe.

> Will this kind of program give unexpected results?

That depends entirely on the body of the thread callback function. You should however wait using `WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE)`. Right now you wait 0ms, which does nothing.

Comment: The question stated that they don't want to wait for the thread to complete, so doing `WaitForSingleObject(hThread,0)` will actually return `WAIT_OBJECT_0` if the thread has exited, but won't put the calling thread into a wait state if it hasn't.  It's one way to check the state of a thread, event, etc.

Comment: @icabod But _somewhere_ in the code you must wait infinitely for the thread to finish. If not in the middle of the program, then at the end. You should never call CloseHandle on the thread before it has finished.

Comment: Indeed, it's a good idea to wait for your threads to finish. I just thought it was worth mentioning that a 0ms wait is a perfectly valid thing to do, and doesn't do nothing - indeed, it actually has quite different behaviour from a wait of any non-zero value.